# AutoFac : MvcApplication Could not be found On mvc 5.2

Tags: c#, autofac, asp.net-mvc-5.2, .net-4.5.2

I want implament Autofac in mvc 5.2 and .net 4.5.2

In this page :https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Mvc5/ In Discription told:

> Dependencies Autofac (>= 4.0.0 && < 5.0.0) Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc (>=
>   5.1.0 && < 6.0.0)
>
> and Updated to .NET 4.5.1, Autofac 4 compatibility

in my project i used mvc 5.2 and dot net 4.5.2

how can implement Autofac on my project ?

Quick Start MVC (this page : http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/mvc.html#quick-start) told:

> // Register your MVC controllers.
>   `builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);`

When I put `typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly` on my ***Global.asax.cs*** file and ***Application_Start*** method 
like this :

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    #region code for AutoFac DI Ioc

    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    //Register your mvc Controolers
    builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);

    //Set the dependecy resolver to be Autofac
    var container = builder.Build();
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));

    #endregion
}
```

But get an error:

> The type or namespace name 'MvcApplication' could not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly refrence?)
>
> Cannot resolve symbol MvcApplication*"

I think snip code has for mvc 4 file *Instead* Global.asax.cs in mvc5

How can I fix it?

Comment: So you get a compile error that the `MvcApplication` type can't be found? You can use *any* type you want that is located in your MVC project. Typically this is the `MvcApplication` and that is the class that holds your `Application_Start` method. But if you named it differently, use that name.

Comment: `Application_Start` method in `global.asax` file , So I have to change snip code to `builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(Global).Assembly);` ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is out-of-date, but I got the same problem, and I think this could help somebody.

As Steven pointed out, you can use any type that is located in your MVC project. The name "MVCApplication" comes from the generated Global.asax file in case you add a new MVC 5 project to your solution in Visual Studio.

However, if you add a new project as a standard web application or web api 2 application then you may not find this class (at least with this name), thus you will not be able to use it.

First thing to do is check your Global.asax.cs class and find the class (the class name to be precise) that derives from HttpApplication. In my case, the class name was WebApiApplication (I am not sure, but I think I started the project by adding web api controllers, and that was the problem).

So try using that name : `builder.RegisterControllers(typeof("whatevertheclassnameinglobal.asax.cs").Assembly);`
in your code first and see the results.